# Combine multiple numpy arrays together with different types together

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have 2 multidimensional numpy arrays in which the elements inside of them can be of different data types. I want to concatenate these arrays together into one singular array.

Basically I have arrays that look like this:

```
a = [['A', 4, 0.5], ['B', 2, 1.9], ['F', 5, 2.0]]
b = [['Positive'], ['Negative'], ['Positive']]
```

Then I would like the combined array to look like this:

```
c = [['A', 4, 0.5, 'Positive'], ['B', 2, 1.9, 'Negative'], ['F', 5, 2.0, 'Positive']]
```

I currently have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

def combine_instances(X, y):
    combined_list = []
    for i,val in enumerate(X):
        combined_list.append(__chain_together(val, y[0]))
    result = np.asarray(combined_list)
    return result

def __chain_together(a, b):
    return list(chain(*[a,b]))
```

However, the resulting array converts every element into string, rather than conserving its original type, is there a way to combine these arrays without converting the elements into a string?

Comment: Why do you want array?  Why not list, which readily handles mixed content?  I don't think you have read enough `numpy` basics.

Comment: `np.array(['A', 1, 3])` creates a string dtype array, because strings are most common type.  It can't convert the letter to numbers.  You could create `object` dtype arrays, but I suspect you don't understand `numpy` well enough to make good use of such an array.

Answer (score 2):

You could [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together and loop over it in plain Python:

```
>>> a = [['A', 4, 0.5], ['B', 2, 1.9], ['F', 5, 2.0]]
>>> b = [['Positive'], ['Negative'], ['Positive']]

>>> c = []
>>> for ai, bi in zip(a, b):
...    c.append(ai + bi)

>>> c
[['A', 4, 0.5, 'Positive'],
 ['B', 2, 1.9, 'Negative'],
 ['F', 5, 2.0, 'Positive']]
```

You can then convert it to a NumPy object array:

```
>>> np.array(c, dtype=np.object)
array([['A', 4, 0.5, 'Positive'],
       ['B', 2, 1.9, 'Negative'],
       ['F', 5, 2.0, 'Positive']], dtype=object)
```

---

Or a one-liner:

```
>>> np.array([ai + bi for ai, bi in zip(a, b)], dtype=np.object)
```

Comment: With this I get an error saying  unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Also I think this solution converts everything to a string, I don't want to have '2' or '1.9' in my resulting array, but rather to conserve their original datatypes of 2 and 1.9

Comment: You're correct, I have edited my answer to keep the same types. Regarding  your first comment, are you sure you are testing with the same inputs `a` and `b`?